# Program hanging every time I execute a query

Tags: c++, mysql

For some reason I don't know, the program crashes when it tries to execute

```
mysql_query(mysql,"CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25))");
```

Though the query gets executed successfully and the table does get created , windows complain that the program stopped responding but it hasn't.

Here's my main function.

```
int main()
{
    MYSQL* mysql;
    mysql_init(mysql);
    mysql_real_connect(mysql,"localhost","root","xxxx","test",0,NULL,0);
    mysql_query(mysql,"CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25))"); // 'Program stops responding' without actually crashing.
    mysql_close(mysql);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your return values. What do they say? Do you drop the table before you run the program again?

Comment: Nope , neither one actually crash. Windows will pop a warning stating that the program has stopped working but when I click "OK" it resumes and proceeds to getchar();

Comment: @Dave Rager Yes, I'm using HeidiSQL drop it before I run the program again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use of the API is wrong, you're passing a dangling pointer to `mysql_init` and *not checking a single return value*. Don't do that.

You can transform your code like this:

```
MYSQL* mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
if (!mysql) {
  // HANDLE THE ERROR
}
if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql,"localhost","root","xxxx","test",0,NULL,0)) {
  // HANDLE THE ERROR
}
if (mysql_query(mysql,"CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25))")) {
  // HANDLE THE ERROR
}
mysql_close(mysql); // No error checking here, that's ok,
                    // it doesn't report errors
                    // But just for this call. All others => check.
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! God bless you all! RIP Mj.

Comment: I believe mysql_query returns 0 on success. So it should read 

if (mysql_query(mysql,"CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25))")) {
  // HANDLE THE ERROR
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql));
      mysql_close(mysql);
      exit(1);
}

Comment: @Begui: fixed. Surprising no-one else complained about that in all this time... thanks.